# Minimizing the browser window should not hide the last item in the navbar menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap menu, the last item in this menu is "More"  which is a dropdown contains the left items from that menu, the problem is when user minimize the window the last items start hiding include "More" item.

So my question is: how to avoid the last item ("More") from being hide?

I searched the internet I could not find any solution, I found many are talking about pull left but it did not work for me.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="category-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav  navbar-nav ">
    <li >
        <a  href="/items/a">a</a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a  href="/items/b">b</a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a  href="/items/c">c</a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a  href="/items/d">d</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown ">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    More
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    @Html.Action("GetMoreCategories", "Items")
                </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any suggestion please?

Feel free to ask for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the styles over - could be some class name with a breakpoint for display:none on that class. Have a look in Devtools and see what it's throwing out?

As far as your code goes, it looks fine so just check over the CSS, positioning and display, etc.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="category-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="/items/a">a</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/items/b">b</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/items/c">c</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/items/d">d</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                @Html.Action("GetMoreCategories", "Items")
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hiding the items one by one when minimizing the window is the default behavior for bootstrap navbar, what I'm looking for is to keep the last item which is "More" in my case.